# No Module Named Facebook error Py2exe

Tags: python, module, py2exe, named

I have the following problem , my script works perfect , but when I compiled with py2exe throws me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "MyFile.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named facebook
```

I tried to create a folder called " facebook " in the build folder, but it is throwing error. This time type :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File  "MyFile.py", line 13, in <module>
   File "facebook\__init__pyc", line 103, in get_object
   File "facebook\__init__pyc", line 245, in request
   File "requests\api.pyc", line 50, in request
   File "requests\session.pyc", line 465, in request
   File "requests\session.pyc", line 573, in send
   File "requests\adapters.pyc", line 431, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:344: error:0B084002:x509 
certificate routines: X509_load_cert_crl_file: system lib
```

My code is very simple to use and works just fine without compilation:

```
> from facepy import GraphAPI
> import facebook
> graph = facebook.GraphAPI(AccessToken)
> graph.get_object()
```

This is my setup.py file in p2exe

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import os
setup(console=['MyFile.py'])
```

**Thank you very much to all**

Comment: You should post the error messages here as text instead of an image.

Comment: where is facebook.py located?

Comment: I 'm using   "Facebook-sdk-master"  There is no file called facebook.py  =(

Answer (score 0):

put this in your script above you "import facebook"

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/some/path") #this is the directory that facebook.py is in
```

Comment: Thanks.... i tried and the new error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "facebook.pyc", line 99, in get_object
  File "facebook.pyc", line 295, in request
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 127, in urlopen
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 402, in open
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 1113, in do_request_
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>

Comment: My problem is that i dont find file "facebook.py", in "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\" my scritp just use  "facebook_sdk-1.0.0_alpha-py2.7.egg"